I cannot run ros2_control_node, controller_manager in ROS2
First of all, I am using translation because my English is not good. II apologize in advance for my spelling and rule mistakes. I am working on an AGV project. I am running the project by taking an example from someone I follow on YouTube. Many people use Raspberry Pi and Arduino in their projects. However, I am using Jetson xaiver. My problem is as follows, when I run the launch_robot.launch.py file, I get this error:
ss@sss:~/robot_ws$ ros2 launch agv_bot launch_robot.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ss/.ros/log/2024-10-24-17-07-21-475349-sss-12553
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [twist_mux-1]: process started with pid [12555]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [12557]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-3]: process started with pid [12559]
[twist_mux-1] [INFO] [1729778842.223705032] [twist_mux]: Topic handler 'topics.navigation' subscribed to topic 'cmd_vel': timeout = 0.500000s , priority = 10.
[twist_mux-1] [INFO] [1729778842.226417305] [twist_mux]: Topic handler 'topics.tracker' subscribed to topic 'cmd_vel_tracker': timeout = 0.500000s , priority = 20.
[ros2_control_node-3] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[ros2_control_node-3] what(): no ros2_control tag
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-3]: process has died [pid 12559, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_45bztatn --params-file /home/ss/robot_ws/install/agv_bot/share/agv_bot/config/my_controllers. yaml'].
[joint_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1729778845.182836751] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...

A lot of time passes and it doesn't keep working.
my_controller.yaml:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 30
    ros2_control:
      type: ros2_control/ControllerManager

    diff_cont:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController
      ros__parameters:
        publish_rate: 50.0
        base_frame_id: base_link
        left_wheel_names: ['left_wheel_joint']
        right_wheel_names: ['right_wheel_joint']
        wheel_separation: 0.42
        wheel_radius: 0.45

    joint_broad:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

launch_robot.launch.py:
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    package_name = 'agv_bot'
    
    # Set the path of the robot definition
    robot_description_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'description', 'robot_core.urdf')

    # Read URDF file
    with open(robot_description_path, 'r') as urdf_file:
        robot_description = urdf_file.read()

    # Twist mux
    twist_mux_params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'config', 'twist_mux.yaml')
    twist_mux = Node(
        package=“twist_mux”,
        executable=“twist_mux”,
        parameters=[twist_mux_params],
        remappings=[('/cmd_vel_out', '/diff_cont/cmd_vel_unstamped')]
    )

    # Joint State Publisher
    joint_state_publisher = Node(
        package=“joint_state_publisher”,
        executable=“joint_state_publisher”,
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description}]
    )

    # Controller Manager
    controller_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'config', 'my_controllers.yaml')
    controller_manager = Node(
        package=“controller_manager”,
        executable=“ros2_control_node”,
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description}, # Provide the robot description here
                    controller_params_file]
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        twist_mux,
        joint_state_publisher,
        controller_manager
    ])

I don't know what to do, can you help me?

The error message is
[ros2_control_node-3] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[ros2_control_node-3] what(): no ros2_control tag

This means that the <ros2_control> section in the URDF is missing, see this section and the linked demos.
